# Is there a good way to replace values in classes for openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have extracted cell values from excel, placed them in classes, and want to replace the wrong values after a specific conversion factor.

I.e something like this at the bottom.
Any suggestions?

````
products = []

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=8, max_row=3030, max_col=10, values_only=True):
    product = Product(id=row[PRODUCT_ID],
                      Molecule=row[PRODUCT_MOLECULE],
                      Pack_Size=row[PRODUCT_PACK_SIZE],
                      Pack_Quantity=row[PRODUCT_PACK_QUANTITY],
                      Product_Treatment=row[PRODUCT_TREATMENT])
    products.append(product)

print(products[1000])

for index, item in enumerate(products):
    if item != PRODUCT_PACK_QUANTITY * PRODUCT_PACK_SIZE / 1:
        products[index] = round(products[index]) - (products[index] PRODUCT_PACK_QUANTITY * PRODUCT_PACK_SIZE / 1)```
````

Comment: I would suggest to use pandas to open the excel with openpyxl and use it as a dataframe and not make and 2d array and iterate on them.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.